# Using Tailwind, how can I apply a ring to an element only when the user tabs to it?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

For accessibility purposes, I want to add a red ring around an element only when the user tabs to it using the keyboard. I can't seem to find the correct attribute in Tailwind to accomplish this.

I have tried to apply a ring through the `focus` pseudo-class, but this makes the ring appear when the user clicks on the button, as well as when they use a tab on the keyboard.

```html
<button
  type="button"
  class="
    inline-flex items-center justify-center w-full rounded-md
    px-4 py-2 bg-white text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-700
    focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-red-200
    active:bg-gray-100 active:text-gray-800
    transition ease-in duration-150
  "
>
Press me
</button>
```

Comment: element is focused both with keyboard and mouse, so that works as intended.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get that effect by using the `focus-visible` modifier.

For example: `class='focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring'`.